# Delphi Rave Report 7.7.0 can Parameters  be used to make multiple lines in a report?

Tags: delphi, report

Ok I am new to rave reports. I have gotten my data aware rave report to work by using bands, but now i need to make a custome report by manauly sending the parameters from the code to the report.

My text book example said I should make parameters for the report I did this and placed them each in a column on the page designer. So for a test i only wanted to fill the first column value Param.Group1 as stated in my text book I used the following code

```
    // Loop at groups;
    rvpgrouprep.SelectReport('grouprep',False);
    rvpgrouprep.open;

    while cdsgrouprep.eof = False do
    begin
      group :=  cdsgrouprep.FindField('GroupName').AsString;
      rvpgrouprep.SetParam('Group1',group);
      cdsgrouprep.MoveBy(1);
    end;

    rvpgrouprep.Execute;
    rvpgrouprep.Close;
```

So my textbook example shows that this should provide a list of groups in the column where param.group1 is on my reprt, but this code only provides one line in my report and that is the last entry. The while loop works I have debuged it. Am I missing something?

Any help is appriciated.

Comment: you are iterating throgh `cdsGroupRep` (dataset?);  may be you have to make something like `Next/MoveBy` with `rvpGroupRep` too? seems you are always trying to set the same parameter (in the same report row)

Comment: I am iterating trough cdsGroupRep(client data set). I agree I should be moving it to the next line, however I havn't found any methode for next/moveby/newline in my textbook or on the internet.

Comment: usually report generators have something like Data-Bands, and you can assign it to dataset (or clientDataSet). take a look at articles here: http://gp.embarcadero.com/authors/edit/1784.aspx Also i've found this manual http://www.bio-work.de/hilfe/bioorderdesk/006/rave5.pdf (RaveReports 5), but it is rather old

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rave is working exactly as designed here. Parameters do not generate a row per each time you change row.

Let's assume since you didn't tell anybody what they mean, that the variable cdsgrouprep is a client data set based group. When a dataset has 4 rows, and you have a band, you naturally expect the banded report generation code in rave to generate 4 copies of that band in your report. But instead of relying on that, what you are probably looking for is something that generates a bunch of rows **completely from code**, and for that you don't need Parameters at all. Parameters are useful, for lots of things, but not exactly what you need here.

Purely Code Based Rave Reports are [shown here](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/30329) in an EDN article, and looks like this:

```
procedure TFormMain.PrintTabularReport(Report: TBaseReport);
var
  FolderList : TStringList;
  i          : Integer;
  NumFiles   : Cardinal;
  NumFolders : Cardinal;
  SizeFiles  : Cardinal;
  Root       : string;
begin
  with Report do
  begin
    SetFont('Arial', 15);
    NewLine;
    PrintCenter('List of Folders in the Drive Root', 4);
    NewLine;
    NewLine;
    ClearTabs;
    SetTab(0.2, pjLeft, 1.7, 0, 0, 0);
    SetTab(1.7, pjRight, 3.1, 0, 0, 0);
    SetTab(3.1, pjRight, 3.5, 0, 0, 0);
    SetTab(3.5, pjRight, 4.5, 0, 0, 0);
    SetFont('Arial', 10);
    Bold := True;
    PrintTab('Folder Name');
    PrintTab('Number of Files');
    PrintTab('Number of Folders');
    PrintTab('Size of Files');
    Bold := False;
    NewLine;
    FolderList := TStringList.Create;
    try
      Root := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(ExtractFileDrive(ParamStr(0)));
      EnumFolders(FolderList, Root);
      for i := 0 to FolderList.Count - 1 do
      begin
        PrintTab(FolderList[i]);
        GetFolderInfo(IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(Root+FolderList[i]),
          NumFiles, NumFolders, SizeFiles);
        PrintTab(Format('%u',[NumFiles]));
        PrintTab(Format('%u',[NumFolders]));
        PrintTab(Format('%u bytes',[SizeFiles]));
        NewLine;
      end;
    finally
      FolderList.Free;
    end;
  end;
```

Comment: Thank You Warren P. I came accrose this Purely Code Based Rave Reports on the web aswell was hoping that I just missed something in the report deigner and text book, but it seems this is the only way to achieve my desired result.